# How to get Switch value from one Activity and display it in other activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am a beginner in Android application development. I'm just trying to get Switch value from one Activity and display it in another activity. But I am getting 'null' as output. Please help me.

**Question1.java**

```
public class Question1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
Switch swi;
Button back1, next1;
String value = "NO";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);
    swi = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.Switch_Ques_1);
    back1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_back1);
    next1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_next1);
    swi.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                swi.setText("YES");
                value="YES";
                swi.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                swi.setText("NO");
                value="NO";
                swi.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }

        }
    });
    back1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Question1Activity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Question1Activity.this,Question2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Ans1",swi.isChecked());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Question3.java**

```
public class Question3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView t1;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question3);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String s1 =(String) intent.getStringExtra("Ans1");
    String s2 = intent.getStringExtra("Ans2");
    t1.setText(s1+" "+s2);
}
}
```

Comment: can you put the error log?

Comment: @Mike M. I have already tried using `intent.getBooleanExtra()`. But it returns the value same as the value that we gave as second parameter. That is `intent.getBooleanExtra("Ans1",false)`. The result was **false**

Answer (score 1):

write as :

```
 String r;
          if(swi.isChecked())
              r = "true";
          else 
              r= "false";
          intent.putExtra("Ans1",r);
```

Instead of

```
 intent.putExtra("Ans1",swi.isChecked());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Question3.java, you are getting the intent method of `getStringExtra` although the value you want to pass is a switch value.

Option 1:  Use `.toString` method to convert the value from the switch widget to get the value in String.

Option 2 (Recommended): Since you already have the setup to take String values in Question3 class, simply pass the `value` string and just get it in the next Activity.

Hope it helps.